# Run two python scripts at the same time

Tags: python

I am an beginner to python and ubuntu.
I am trying to run two python scripts at the same time in terminal,my command in the terminal is:

```
python one.py|python three.py
```

`one.py` prints a four variable array to the terminal

`three.py` reads the values from terminal and stores the values to another array.

I believe this process in ubuntu terminal is called **pipelining**.

The problem now I am facing is the python script `three.py` waits until python script `one.py` to complete its execution. I want it to happen in real time, whenever `one.py` has an output, `three.py` should read and store this value in realtime.

output of one.py

[image: output of one.py screenshot]

code:three.py

[image: code:three.py screenshot]

Comment: If you don't want to wait I think you should look at 'named pipes' (`man pipe`).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your code and output as plain, code-formatted text. Screenshots of text are bad.

Comment: 1) The line `temp=[]` seems to be useless. 2) Possible cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799300/sys-stdin-readlines-hangs-python-script You should ask programming questions on [so] anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of `three.py` is incorrect.

By writing

```py
temp = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

You tell Python to read all lines from standard input and store it as list in your `temp` variable. It's obvious that this call blocks until the input is exhausted, which happens only when `one.py` is finished and exits, closing the pipeline. Only after that you start processing the input.

What you can do instead is to read from standard input line by line in a loop, like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

Comment: @An0n Please refrain from posting non-useful comments and nonsense comments on posts.  Thank you!

Comment: @An0n The same applies for useless edits as well, too.  Knock it off.